# python functions in a formula odd behavior

Tags: python, function, math, formula

I am noticing some odd behavior with my functions when placed in a formula. Here is the raw equation without functions in it:

```
>>> (.39 * 4.0) + (11.8 * 1.5) - 15.59
3.6700000000000017    # the answer im looking for
```

I replaced a few of these numbers with functions that are returning the same number.

```
def average_words(astring):
    word_count = len(re.findall(r'\w+', astring))
    period_count = len(re.findall(r'\.+', astring))
    period_count = period_count or 1
    return word_count/period_count

>> average_words(astring)
4.0


def average_syllables(astring):
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', astring)
    vowels_count = []
    for word in words:

        vowels = len(re.findall(r'[aeiou]+', word))
        vowels_count.append(vowels)
    return  sum(vowels_count)/len(vowels_count)

>>>average_syllables(astring)
1.5
```

But now when I replace the number with the function, it gives me some odd numbers in return

```
>>> (.39 * average_words(astring)) + (11.8 * average_words(astring)) - 15.59
33.17
```

Why is this happening?

Edit:

Full code:

```
import re

def average_words(astring):
    word_count = len(re.findall(r'\w+', astring))
    period_count = len(re.findall(r'\.+', astring))
    period_count = period_count or 1
    return word_count/period_count

def average_syllables(astring):
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', astring)
    vowels_count = []
    for word in words:

        vowels = len(re.findall(r'[aeiou]+', word))
        vowels_count.append(vowels)
    return  sum(vowels_count)/len(vowels_count)

def flesch_kincaid(s):
    """ Takes a string and returns grade level rounded off to two decimal points."""
    return (.39 *  average_words(s)) + (11.8 *  average_syllables(s)) - 15.59


print flesch_kincaid("The turtle is leaving.")
```

Comment: Yes, full code please. In general.

Comment: In the last statement, the second `average_words(astring)` should be `average_syllables(astring)`? So you need to give an example that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @YuHao, I think that's the entire issue.

Comment: How embarrassing. Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the reason I was not getting the desired outcome was not only because I did a silly typo, but also because in my code I was  using division in my functions. These divisions are a bit odd to people from other languages.  To remedy the odd python division I used from `__future__ import division`.

Comment: @Apathy, since you're new to python, you should switch to python 3 right away. One of its advantages is the improved behavior of division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the REPL session, you're doing `(11.8 * average_words(astring))`, not `(11.8 * average_syllables(astring))`. But it's correct in the full code..